# What's the difference between 'can't read property foo of undefined' and 'undefined is not an object'

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, frontend

Recently I get some error messages from our platform, the message is like `undefined is not an object (evaluating 't.id')`, but the associated code is `bar(xxx.id)`

IMO, even it will throw Error, it should be `can't read property id of undefined` rather than `undefined is not an object (evaluating 't.id')`

So, could anyone tell me why this happen? Thanks!

Comment: `t` is `undefined`. You are accessing properties on`undefined` as if it were an object. The parser is telling you that `undefined is not an object` because well, it is `undefined`

Comment: I'm not sure this is really an answerable question? If that's what you're seeing, the answer is just "because that is what the execution engine decided to do".

Comment: The expression is likely processed by first getting the identifier `t`. Then seeing the `.`, then another identifier `id`. So the engine will  say "this looks like dot property access to an object property value", so to resolve the expression it tests `t` to see if it references an object. It doesn't so there's the error. If *t* was an object, then it would proceed to try and find the *id* property and if not found, then there would be a reference error like "can't find property id of object t" or similar.

Comment: Can you offer a piece of code that generates the `undefined is not an object (evaluating 't.id')` message.  I cannot reproduce that specific error in Chrome.

Comment: @jfriend00 I can't reproduce it too, I find this in our error tracking platform, and the corresponding piece of code that generates the error is `bar(xxx.id)` like I describe in the question

Comment: What platform is that error on?  Which browser?  Which version of node.js?

Comment: @jfriend00 We use sentry as the platform, and use the official SDK raven-js for the error capture and processing. The browser is too many, it depends on the users. The node version is 6 two months ago and now is node 8

Comment: I'm trying to figure out if the error is occurring in a browser and, if so, which one in order to try to reproduce it.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks!

Comment: I meant that I'm asking you to tell me which browser it's occurring in.

Comment: @jfriend00 Sorry, my bad. It seems that the browser is always Mobile Safari UI/WKWebView (The page is only in our app)

Comment: OK, that's one browser I don't have the ability to test in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I thinks maybe it's because different browsers have different error handling

In safari:

[image]

In chrome:

[image]

<del>But I think the error message should be same because the ECMAScript spec has clear definition about this</del>

This is not correct, from comments of @Bergi:

> But I think the error message should be same because the ECMAScript spec has clear definition about this" - not at all. It just says that a TypeError should be thrown, and the implementation may decide to provide an appropriate (helpful) error message as they see fit. It doesn't even have to be in English

Comment: Yep, that appears to be it.

Comment: "*But I think the error message should be same because the ECMAScript spec has clear definition about this*" - not at all. It just says that a `TypeError` should be thrown, and the implementation may decide to provide an appropriate (helpful) error message as they see fit. It doesn't even have to be in English.